# Nestjs-query: sorting by one-to-one relation field

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-typeorm, nestjs-query

With [nestjs-query](https://doug-martin.github.io/nestjs-query/docs/graphql/queries#filtering) we can filter by nested relations:

```
{
  todoItems(
    filter: {nested: {completed: {is: true}}},
    sorting: {field: "title", direction: "ASC"},
   ){
    pageInfo{
      hasNextPage
      hasPreviousPage
      startCursor
      endCursor
    }
    edges{
      node{
        id
        title
        completed
        created
        updated
      }
      cursor
    }
  }
}
```

Can we do something like that with [sorting](https://doug-martin.github.io/nestjs-query/docs/graphql/queries#sorting)?

Option [lookahead](https://tripss.github.io/nestjs-query/docs/graphql/relations/#graphql-lookahead) is turned on. I use [FilterableRelation](https://doug-martin.github.io/nestjs-query/docs/graphql/relations#filterablerelation). TypeORM.